# I don't know how to simplify resistors which have 2 grounds

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors

I think that I can't apply normal Thevenin method and mesh method. How I can I simplify it? I don't think it is really parallel because that has mid ground.

If some online site has same form like this, can you do take about that?

I don't need the need answer, but I hope to get advice and how to operate process.

I simulated that, but the voltage graph was not sine wave. Just weird.

[image]

I thevnined that circuit and made under circuit.
[image]

Comment: @ChrisStratton I simulated that in online multisim, but that voltage graph even not sine wave. I dont know why. there just have resistors only.   blue line is input of non-inverting input

Comment: @ChrisStratton Umm...SOrry about my English ability is not good. that is transformed Vi by resistors.  so..the voltage in blue line maybe driving the non inverting input!

Comment: @ChrisStratton   Ohh really? I didnt know that. okay will upload all.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I did! Hmm.. If i do simplication of resistors, then can do solve well.

Comment: but Having gnd on that circuit..that was first seen even in my book too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by using source transformation like this: -

[image]

I've split the input signal into two identical signals then use thevenin's theorem to produce an equivalent source voltage of two-thirds of \$V_i\$ feeding through the parallel combination of the 1 ohm and 2 ohm resistors that joined at \$V_x\$.

You then simplify the circuit so that the resistors surrounding \$V_x\$ become 1 resistor of 1.6667 ohms fed from two-thirds of \$V_i\$: -

[image]

Then do another thevenin's equivalent with the 1.6667 ohm resistor and the 2 ohm resistor that connects to ground. That gets rid of your resistors going to ground and you will be left with a simple summing op-amp circuit.

Can you finish this yourself?

> *I simulated that, but the voltage graph was not sine wave. Just weird.*

Taking the step to do a simulation is something I always recommend and well-done to you for that. The modern world is here; step into it. Yes, a real (simulated or really real) op-amp with such low impedances will get into a big mess. If you changed all the resistor values from Ω to kΩ it would certainly give it a better chance of working.

Comment: This is the approach I'd take. The OP should quickly find that the total conductance, both branches, is 5/8. So that \$\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}=-\frac58\$. You've walked the OP right up to the answer, so I figured it won't hurt to provide the goal. The OP should be able to work out the stuff in the middle.

Comment: @jonk thank you!! i checked you are right from simulation too! umm but I hope to know how i have to merge 2 different voltage. Anyway I uploaded organized circuit, that is right?

Comment: @RNNmaster You have a diminished (attenuated) version of the input voltage along one branch, with its own Thevenin resistance. This is distinct from the 2 Ohm resistor to the same opamp input node. You can combine them quite easily using nodal analysis to solve for the opamp input node voltage. Have you tried? In any case, I've not bothered to add an answer as you've already selected one (a good one.)

Comment: @jonk Thank you! I solved by nodal analysis! umm but Answer given -11/16.. umm i had a problem about voltage?

Comment: I think your equivalent circuit is wrong. Both Thevenin voltage and resistance. @RNN

Comment: @RNNmaster The node is at virtual ground. I forgot to mention that fact. So I get Vin/2 + [Vin * (4/11)]/(2 + 10/11) = Vin * 5/8 as the current into the node.

Comment: @jonk Thank you! and I am really sorry about ask, umm.. I cant understand about where from 4/11, can you tell me about that one time?

Comment: @RNNmaster  2/3 * 2/(2+1+2/3) = 4/11.

Comment: @MeenieLeis Umm what is wrong? I hope to get advice from you too!

Comment: @MeenieLeis can you explain your comment above - what is it that you see that you believe to be wrong? Is it something to do with my answer?

Comment: @jonk i got ynderstand perfectly in just now !!! thank you!!!

Comment: No Andy. I was talking about RNN's circuit. I think it's to be voltage source 4/11 in series with 32/11 ohms. But he has an additional series resistor 32 ohms and 6/11 as voltage source.

Comment: @MeenieLeis please leave your comment under the question then. Leaving it under my answer (without clear context) is wasting time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Mentally erase all but the 2-ohm resistor between Vi and the inverting input, and the feedback resistor from Vo.  Solve this simpler problem in the standard way, paying careful attention to what assumptions the standard op-amp solution makes.  What can you say about the voltage at the inverting input itself?  What expression can you write for the currents flowing into the inverting input?
2. Return to the real circuit and label the voltage of the inverting input.
3. Start from the right and iteratively simplify the resistor network.  Notice the values given are very suitable for this...
4. Think about the equation you wrote and solved in step 1 for the simpler classic op-amp problem.  Write the equivalent expressions here.

Comment: I will try, but  i successed until Vi ( 2/3) , but T circuit is blocked me. about 1, 2, 2ohm+ground